# What does the symbol $\cong$ mean in the context of congruencies?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

A symbol I have in my math homework looks like a ~ above a =. (That is, $\cong$.)  What does this mean? I'm studying Congruency at the moment if that helps.

Comment: In geometry, this means congruent. In abstract algebra, it usually denotes an isomorphism.

Comment: Since he speaks in the algebra context, it is probably an isomorphism of groups or rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cong$ usually means *congruent* in this context.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry).

Comment: Thank you So Much! I had a hunch that that's what it mean xD  I just like to be extra sure & Google wasn't working.

Comment: @RosaLex, http://detexify.kirelabs.org can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you are studying congruency, I'm guessing you know what congruency means. And $A\cong B$ means that $A$ is congruent to $B$.

Answer (score 0):

If it is used between two numbers followed by a third number in parenthesis like $a\cong b\pmod m$ then it means both the numbers will give the same remainder upon division by $m$. If it is used between two capital letters such as $A\cong B$, then it could possibly mean those two  are groups and  are isomorphic.

Comment: shoulda be $a\equiv b\pmod m$?

Comment: You are right, $\equiv$ is the more traditional symbol for congruence. (Introduced by Gauss?) But in this question when the context was given I cannot think of anything else.